# How to run Vuejs tests with without JsDom?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, jestjs, jsdom, vue-test-utils

I have a Vuejs project with Jest and [Vue test utils](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#).

Currently I'm running my unit tests in [JsDom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) test environment.

I want to change my test environment to "node", because it's a lot faster and as I understand in latest jest they [decided to switch](https://jestjs.io/blog/2021/05/25/jest-27) to "node" as well.

But when I set my `jest.config.js` to

```
 testEnvironment: 'node',
```

I start to receive a lot of errors, such as

```
[vue-test-utils]: window is undefined, vue-test-utils needs to be run in a browser environment.
You can run the tests in node using jsdom
```

But I guess there should be a way to lunch them with 'node', cause I hardly doubt that jest and the React community decided for that switch with no reason.
Feels like I missed a couple of steps.

So, my question is: what should I do to run my test in 'node'?

Comment: Jest switched default because for a lot of users (writing Node only apps for example) the "node" environment is better. If your code needs browser environment (as Vue Test Utils do) you still need "JsDom"

Comment: *because it's a lot faster* - it's faster for a reason. Because it implements no DOM. You can't run tests that need DOM without DOM.